# Python Nested For Loops .

Tags: python, python-3.x

using For Loop (any better option?) over the list and dictionary below, I'm trying to print out a set such that the print out should be: 
One 1 b
Two 2 b
Three 3 c
. . .

Below is what I tried but I can't seem to get the desired output.

I tried to use the break statement at certain spots too, but didn't get the correct output.

How do I go about to achieve this?

Thanks!

```
alpha_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
num_list = [1, 2, 3]


dicttt = {"One": [1, 2, 3], "Two": [2, 3, 4], "Three": [3, 4, 5], "Four": [4, 5, 6], "Five": [5, 6, 7], 
        "Six": [6, 7, 8], "Seven": [7, 8, 9], "Eight": [8, 9, 10], "Nine": [9, 10, 11], "Ten": [10, 11, 12]}




for key, value in dicttt.items():

    for i in num_list:

        for alpha in alpha_list:
            print(key, i, alpha)
```

The output from the above code is:

```
One 1 a
One 1 b
One 1 c
One 1 d
One 1 e
One 1 f
One 1 g
One 1 h
One 1 i
One 1 j
One 1 k
One 1 l
One 2 a
One 2 b
One 2 c
One 2 d
```

.....

Comment: use `zip` instead of double loop. But wait: you cannot as dictionaries aren't ordered. You have no way of iterating on `dicttt` with the declaration order unless using python 3.6

Comment: What is `num_list`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Given Python 3.6 has been out for 2.5 years (and 3.7 for a year), assuming ordered `dict`s isn't so unreasonable at this point. Can't do it for packages you plan to release online for all supported versions of Python (3.5 isn't quite at EOL), but it's fine for personal scripts.

Comment: What happens for the letter `l`? you don't have a `Eleven` there

Comment: Why is it `One 1 b`, not `One 1 a`?

Comment: As I mentioned, expected output that I want is:
One 1 a
Two 2 b
Three 3 c

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from `itertools` like this:

```py
from itertools import product, chain

alpha_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

dicttt = {"One": [1, 2, 3], "Two": [2, 3, 4], "Three": [3, 4, 5], "Four": [4, 5, 6], "Five": [5, 6, 7],
          "Six": [6, 7, 8], "Seven": [7, 8, 9], "Eight": [8, 9, 10], "Nine": [9, 10, 11], "Ten": [10, 11, 12]}

options = chain(*[list(product((k,), v, alpha_list)) for k, v in dicttt.items()])

for key, i, alpha in options:
    print(key, i, alpha)
```